# Regex to find same string occuring on adjacent lines

Tags: regex

I am not very good at regex but a need has arisen to use it to search through hundreds of log files to find a specific occurence.  I have normally been able to use them in the past to find all occurences of a word or phrase but this time i need something a bit more complicated (I think).

The log file looks like this:

```
2013-03-05 14:57:58 DEBUG [Dossier returned: ]
2013-03-05 14:57:58 DEBUG [Dossier sent: ] htt
2013-03-05 14:57:59 DEBUG [Dossier returned: ]
2013-03-05 14:58:02 DEBUG [Dossier sent: ] htt
2013-03-05 14:58:49 DEBUG [Dossier sent: ] htt
2013-03-05 14:58:50 DEBUG [Dossier returned: ]
2013-03-05 14:58:50 DEBUG [Dossier sent: ] htt
2013-03-05 14:58:50 DEBUG [Dossier returned: ]
```

The only occurence I would like to find is where [Dossier sent: ] appears on adjacent lines.  This highlights an error in the program.  Would be grateful for any assistance.

EDIT: thanks for the guidance.  I am using powershell to parse over the text files.  so the regex is running within this.

Comment: So, you only want to capture `[Dossier sent: ]` and not `[Dossier returned: ]`?

Comment: what language/tool do you use?

Comment: @deadlock it is clear `I would like to find is where [Dossier sent: ] appears on adjacent lines.`

Answer (score 0):

If you want to match the whole line where `[Dossier sent: ]` appears. Then you should use:

```
^.+?Dossier\ssent:.+?$
```

On the other hand, if you are trying to capture whatever between the square brackets, then you can use:

```
DEBUG\s([[].+?[]])
```

Comment: you didn't give what OP wants.

Comment: @Kent It's what he wanted before he edited the answer. I am updating the answer once I understand the question :)

Comment: oh, sorry, I missed that part... sorry

Answer (score 0):

Depending on what language you are using matching across multiple lines may work differently.
You could try this though:

```
^.*\[Dossier sent: \].*\n.*\[Dossier sent: \].*$
```

Or we could shorten it using a backreference:

```
^.*(\[Dossier sent: \]).*\n.*\1.*$
```

Answer (score 0):

Using multi-line mode, this worked for me:

```
(.*?\[Dossier sent: \].*?(?:\n|\Z)){2}
```